# Magento - Integrity constraint viloation: 1452, shopping cart rules

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

When making a discount/shopping cart rule for a given category or SKU number, it's unable to save and this error is created:

```
'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop1`.`salesrule_product_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALESRULE_PRD_ATTR_CSTR_GROUP_ID_CSTR_GROUP_CSTR_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_i)' in /var/www/shop1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

I've been looking through my DB to find the problem, but without luck. I'm unsure where to start looking now, I found no obvious errors in the customer_group table, but I think it has something to do with a deleted store front, a while ago, maby messing up the customer id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the most Obvious reason, was the last one that I checked! - The ´customer_group´ table was set to MyISAM instead of InnoDB, it **must be InnoDB.**